# CollectionView visible on the view hierarchy debugger but not on the simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

I'm trying to add this collectionView inside a UIView, and it shows perfectly with the view hierarchy debugger, but not with the running app, any idea about what could I check?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmdUf.png)

Comment: please provide some code samples on how both UIView and UICollectionView are added to the main view. It is hard to guess what could've gone wrong without context

Comment: 1 - When you capture the view hierarchy, there is an option to `Show Clipped Content` that will show any views presented outside of the bounds of the phone. 2 - Make sure that your storyboard and your simulator are set for the same device.  If the simulator is smaller than the storyboard, then items will be clipped.

Answer (score 1):

`.alpha` of the collectionView is likely set to 0. If so view hierarchy debugger will still display as it as a normally appearing `UIView`.